# I am facing issue with IBM API connect when I configure the API connect using static IP address

Tags: ibm-cloud, high-availability, apiconnect

I am facing issue with IBM API connect when I configure the API connect using static IP address but it is working fine with DHCP IP address.

Some logs I found in logger are

> [org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractOsgiBundleApplicationContext.unpublishContextAsOsgiService]
>   Unpublishing application context OSGi service for bundle
>   spring-osgi-web-extender (org.springframework.osgi.web.extender)
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>
> [org.springframework.osgi.web.deployer.support.AbstractWarDeployer.deploy]
>   Successfully deployed bundle [cmc (com.ibm.apimgmt.cmc.war)] at [/cmc]
>   on server org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService/1.0
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>
> [com.ibm.apimgmt.util.events.x2020.X2020EventPoster$X2020EventPosterRunnable.run]
>   Could not POST to: http://localhost:9500/cmc/monitoringevent
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Please provide me your guidance.

Thanks & Regards,
Vijaykumar

Answer (score 0):

DHCP (Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol) dynamically allocates IP addresses to a requesting host from a pool of IP addresses. While a DHCP server may preferentially allocate the same IP address to the same host for multiple requests, it is not *guaranteed*.

In contrast, a static IP address stays permanently associated to a host. In your case, the static IP address and the DHCP-assigned IP address do not match. Your connection goes through to the specific IP address you are trying to call. This target system may or may not exist. If such a system does exist, it will likely not be listening at the target port.

This is corroborated by the fact that you are getting a `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` error.